# Flash streaming audio issue: audio playing multiple times only on frame change

Tags: flash, audio, streaming, playback, overlapping

Okay, so, here's the deal: i'm making a quiz game, and i decided to put a soundtrack to it. It is a single audio file that i uploaded to my custom domain and have it streaming through code. I also added play/pause buttons so that the player can , obviously, play and pause the music. The music autoplays on frame 1, where the "start" button of my game is. However, if the player answers a question wrong, he goes back to the first frame. The problem is that another "instance" of the music starts playing, resulting in 2 music playing on the same time. If he answers wrong again , there will be three music playback, and so on.... i need some sort of event listener that keeps this from happening... As you can see i already tried using the boolean method, but it doesn't work...
Here's the code i've used for the streaming:

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var lastPosition:Number = 0;// pause button
mySound.load(new URLRequest("http://trollfacequiz.16mb.com/MusicFiles/Goat%20Songs.mp3"));
var soundIsPlaying:Boolean = false;
//mySound.play();
myChannel = mySound.play();

btn_mute.pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPause);

function onClickPause(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    lastPosition = myChannel.position;
    myChannel.stop();
    soundIsPlaying = false;
}
btn_mute.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPlay);

function onClickPlay(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (soundIsPlaying == false)
    {
        myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition);
        soundIsPlaying = true;
    }
}
```

btn_mute is a movie clip symbol that contains both play and pause buttons.
btn_pause is the pause button.
btn_play is the play button obviously.
The pause button is on top of the play button, so that when it gets invisible it "becomes" the play button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is in your code structure and putting codes in frames and the shortest way to solve the problem is using SoundMixer.stopAll();

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var lastPosition:Number = 0;// pause button
mySound.load(new URLRequest("http://trollfacequiz.16mb.com/MusicFiles/Goat%20Songs.mp3"));
var soundIsPlaying:Boolean = false;
//mySound.play();
SoundMixer.stopAll();
myChannel = mySound.play();

btn_mute.pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPause);

function onClickPause(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    lastPosition = myChannel.position;
    myChannel.stop();
    soundIsPlaying = false;
}
btn_mute.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPlay);

function onClickPlay(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (soundIsPlaying == false)
    {
        myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition);
        soundIsPlaying = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works as a charm xD                                            I just have one question: why doesn't the soundMixer.stopAll "reset" the sound? cause if the frame is entered, sound mixer stops all sonds and then myChannel = mySound.play() plays it, theoretically resetting the sound...

Comment: You mean in the wrong answer case the sound continues to play from last position?? maybe it could help mySound.play(0);

Comment: I think you got it wrong, your code works perfectly, i just wanted to know why didn't the soundMixer.stopAll reset the sound, cause i tought it did...

Comment: no it doesn't it just stops all previous sounds when you comeback to this frame. and your code starts the new sound again. 
your previous code doesn't stop previous sound object so that you had duplicate sound.